# Django retrieve most recent model per day for each item in a list of foreign keys

Tags: python, django, orm

I'm looking for the most efficient way to do the following:

I have the following model:

```
class DataEntry(models.Model):
    signal_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)#FK to Signal.name without telling Django (or the database) the relationship (LONG STORY, OUT OF MY HANDS)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField()
    value = models.FloatField()
```

I have a list of signal names (strings) and a list of days. I need to retrieve the most recent DataEntry for each signal name in the signal list for each day in the list of days.  Essentially...

```
for signal in signal_list:
    for day in day_list:
        next_day =  day + timedelta(days=1)
        entry_list.append(DataEntry.objects
            .filter(timestamp__lt=next_day)
            .filter(signal_name=signal)
            .order_by("-timestamp")[0])
```

This seems like it would generate a TON of database calls. Is there any ORM trickery I can utilize to turn this into as few database calls as possible?

Comment: Are all your days distinct or consecutive?

Comment: they are both unique and consecutive.  I'll be doing this for every day in a 2 week span, as well as porting it to months and years...all of which will be consecutive.

Comment: What database are you using, specifically? I fear this'll require database-specific additional syntax which the Django ORM is not sophisticated enough for to handle.

Comment: this is using mysql in AWS RDS

Comment: Hrm, the Django ORM is rather.. clunky. I am not in a position right now to test my efforts, but you basically would filter on the whole range (`filter(timestamp__range=(earliest_timestap, latest_timestamp))` then group_by on the date portion only, selecting the `Max()` for each date column. This requires an `.extra()` call to extract just the date portion of each timestamp.